# Laravel Polimorphic Relation Pass Dynamically Type

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

i used polimorphic relation in laravel but my problem is, how to pass relation_type dynamically (Example:When i want to create tickets for Organization pass Organization Model namespace or for Contact pass Contact Model namespace).

This is my model

**class Ticket**

```
public function relation(){
  return $this->morphTo();
}
```

**class Organization**

```
public function tickets(){
   return $this->morphMany('Ticket','relation');
}
```

**class Contact**

```
public function tickets(){
   return $this->morphMany('Ticket','relation');
}
```

i don't now it is possible but i want a function that accept two param

```
public function ticketRelation($model, $Id){
     $modelNamespace = $model::findById($id); 
     $ticket = new Ticket();
     $ticket->save();
     $modelNamespace->tickets()->save($ticket);    
}
```

In this casse a $model param should be accept Organization or Contact to associate new ticket
And if i realize this i need only one route that accept a model and an Id to associate new ticket.How to pass an class like a param in this method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do to link a Ticket to either Organization or Contact is:

```
$organization = new Organization;
$organization->save();

$contact = new Contact();
$contact->save();

$organizationTicket = new Ticket;
$organizationTicket->relation()->associate($organization);
$organizationTicket->save();

$contactTicket = new Ticket;
$contactTicket ->relation()->associate($contact);
$contactTicket ->save();
```

Yes, it is possible to achieve what you want with your function.

Since PHP 5.3 it is possible to dynamically call class static methods on a variable containing class name, so if $model contains a valid namespaced class name you can just do:

```
public function ticketRelation($class, $id){
     $model= $class::findOrFail($id); 
     $ticket = new Ticket();
     $ticket->relation()->associate($model);
     $ticket->save();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @jedrzej.kurylo i find solution.